# Working copy got mysteriously unlinked from repository. How to relink it again and commit changes?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoisesvn under windows 7. My working copy got mysteriously unlinked from the repository. How can I relink my working copy to the repository  and commit changes?

Comment: What do you mean by "unlinked from repository"? Are there any error messages or does the context menu not show the SVN commands you expect?

Comment: The .svn folder disappeared, the context menu is different, I cannot commit or anything else. Only few options. No icon on the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout a new working copy from the repository and copy the files from the damaged working copy into the new folder. Now you should see the modified files in the `pending changes` dialog and can commit them.