# Moved everything to my new computer. Installed tortoise svn. How can I relink again all the working copy to the repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I bought a new laptop. I copied all the working copies from my old laptop to my new one. I installed tortoise svn  (under windows 7). Now my working copy clearly have no tortoise icon on the folder. But I have the .svn hidden folder, however the context menu (when I right click) is different, I cannot commit or else. Only few options. How can I get the same configuration I had in the old laptop, with the Tortoise icon on the folder and where by right clicking I could get the extended menu allowing me to commit? The answer to a similar (but different since there .svn folder was gone) question I asked here [Working copy got mysteriously unlinked from repository. How to relink it again and commit changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978107/working-copy-got-mysteriously-unlinked-from-repository-how-to-relink-it-again-a) is too cumbersome to be used multiple times in all the working copies.

Comment: post a picture of the new context menu. My guess is, that you have installed a newer TSVN version compared to yur old computer and you need to upgrade the working copies to a higher version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to do right click and choose "SVN upgrade the working copy". It is outside the tortoiseSVN menu so I did not initially notice it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check settings and configuration of TSVN (Icon overlays enabled, drive of your WCes is not in excluded-drives list)
2. Check functionality of TSVN per se: create local repo, checkout from it (even empty) to some-new-WC, check overlays presence
3. **The most possible version**: Propreties of WC-folder - Subversion tab. Inspect URL of repository and it's accessibility from new workplace: it can be file:///-based repository, not existing now, or remote host, not reachable (for some reason)