# After harddrive crash, how to "relink" folders to TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

My harddrive crashed, but we were able to retrieve all the data.

When I rightclick on the folder that was previously the folder in which my working copy was, then it gives me the options: "SVN Upgrade working copy" or "TortoiseSVN" with -> Repo-browser, Properties, Setttings, Help, About.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978107/working-copy-got-mysteriously-unlinked-from-repository-how-to-relink-it-again-a) gives a possible solution, but I don't want to checkout everything again. I have all the files, I just want TortoiseSVN to recognise that the folder contains my working copy and sync with it again.

I don't know the jargon. I guess I could go and read the documentation, but I don't quite know what I'm looking for, or what it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SVN Upgrade working copy" means, in short - "Installed now version of TSVN/SVN is radically newer, than used on creating WC" (format of WC was changed some times during SVN-lifrcycle) and *this* WC can't be used with *this* SVN-client (TortoiseSVN)

You have two opposite ways:

- Downgrade your client to version, which can work with this WC (a bit divination - your TortoiseSVN is current 1.9 or previous 1.8, but WC of 1.6 format: last change of WC-format was in 1.6->1.7 update AFAICR)
- (As suggested) Upgrade your WC to required format for existing client (I'll recommend do it in command-line (read `svn help upgrade`) on previously backup'ed WC)

Check|show content of `.svn\format` file + version of your TSVN|SVN, I'll be able to shed some additional light (differing only in the details) on your situation of incompability

Comment: It seems that simply using "SVN Upgrade Working Copy" has done the trick. The icons appeared again, and I could commit the changes.